# Get the perimeter of a list of verticies

Tags: c#, polygon, vertices, collider

I am currently developing a level editor, and I've gotten to the point where I have collected a list of vertices that I want to use to create a Polygon collider.

I have obtained these vertices by tagging certain tiles as "colliders" and running them through an algorithm to get a list of tiles that are connected. I then created a list of vertices from the list of connected tiles and removed any duplicates.

Below is an image that will help explain. All of the dots are verticies that are currently in my list, but I want to use the ones colored red to create a polygon.

[image]

Comment: "Convex hull" would be good search term... But you are looking for something less defined - if you provide much better explanation of how you define if pair of points belong to border you may get answer here or maybe on [Cs.se]

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to find. I currently don't have a way to find if a vertex is on the side, or on the corner, or neither.

Comment: You have to stare at the picture and figure out what rules you used when draw it. Also try more interesting pictures (I.e. draw letters with dots and than find border for them) . At that point you hopefully will have better idea what you want and will be able to clarify this question.

Comment: I sort of did that, and I came up with the idea to do an adjacency test on every vertex. If it has exactly 2 neighbors, it is a corner, and if it has exactly 3 neighbors it is an edge.

Comment: Note that this is not an explanation of how you did that by hand... It is something that is likely close to solution (you obviously find inner corner interesting) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving my problem. Each vertex is a part of four different tiles (Excluding edge of map cases), so I just iterated through every vertex and counted how many neighbors are "of the same type". If the result was 4 then it meant that the vertex was somewhere in the middle of the polygon. If the result was 3 it meant the vertex was on an inner corner. 2 meant it was on an edge. 1 meant it was an outer corner.

```
private List<Vector2> GetPerimeterOfVerticeList(List<Vector2> vertices, TileType type)
{
    int neighborCount = 0;
    List<Vector2> perimeter = new List<Vector2>();

    //Check the four tiles touching this vertex
    foreach (Vector2 v in vertices)
    {
        //upper left tile
        if (v.x - 1 >= 0 && v.y <= gridHeight - 1 && grid[(int)v.x - 1, (int)v.y].type == type)
        {
            neighborCount++;
        }
        //upper right
        if (v.x <= gridWidth - 1 && v.y <= gridHeight - 1 && grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y].type == type)
        {
            neighborCount++;
        }
        //bottom right
        if (v.y - 1 >= 0 && v.x <= gridWidth - 1 && grid[(int)v.x, (int)v.y - 1].type == type)
        {
            neighborCount++;
        }
        //bottom left
        if (v.y - 1 >= 0 && v.x - 1 >= 0 && grid[(int)v.x - 1, (int)v.y - 1].type == type)
        {
            neighborCount++;
        }


        //If we have less than 4 neighbors, it means we are on the edge. 3 is an inner corner, 2 is a side piece, 1 is an outer corner
        if (neighborCount < 4)
        {
            perimeter.Add(v);
        }

        //Reset the neighbor count back to 0 for the next vertex check.
        neighborCount = 0;
    }
    return perimeter;
}
```